# rails - escaping whitespace and quotes for use in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

I am trying to do the following in an ajax call

index.js.erb

```
$("#dialog").text("<%= render("index") %>")
```

It tells me in my js console that there's an unterminated string literal (which is true because there are quotes and whitespace in the partial.

I have tried to use escape_javascript but it then displays the partial code. I have also tried calling raw(escape_javascript(render("index")) with no success.

I think all I need to do is escape the double quotes and remove the whitespace. Is there a function for this?

Cheers
Tim

Comment: What does `raw(escape_javascript(render("index"))` give?

Comment: a string with the newlines replaced by \n and both quotes escaped... eg. <script type=\'text/javascript\'>\n  //<![CDATA[\n    $(function () {\n      var selected = [21589,21590,21349,21238,20793,21349,21589,21590,20795]\n    \n      function getKlass(id, href, all_selected) {\n        var klass = $(\"#klass_\"+id)\n    \n        $(\".klass\").removeClass(\"selected\")\n        $(\"#k\"+id).addClass(\"selected\")\n

Answer (score 5):

Ok the problem was not the escaping but the automatic encoding that the jQuery text method was using.

I used

```
$("#dialog").text("")
$("#dialog").append("<%= render(escape_javascript("index")).html_safe %>")
```

Hard to find because my Firebug was lying to me and showing me the rendered characters not the encoded versions.